# Study vs Education as modifiers

Tags: word-usage, meaning-in-context, differences, attributive-nouns

Could you describe the difference in contexts/connotations for "Study" and "Education" as modifiers, particularly in "study programs" and "education programs" at the university - might be my question is also about style, fell free to express your views, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Study programs** and **education programs** are virtually synonyms in this sense. They are basically the same thing.

However, most people might tend to think that **study programs** indicates more intense or active "studying" or maybe "group study" or possibly more self learning is involved. Whereas **"education programs"** would tend to give a broader sense of education, classroom learning, etc... without necessarily a particular study focus or activity associated with it.

That's really the only difference I can think of at the moment.